# chrome 64 bit youtube videos grainy

Tags: 12.10, flash, google-chrome

Not sure if this the right forum for this question.
Anyway in Chrome browser, Youtube videos are grainy as shown in this image.

[image: Youtube grainy images]

There seems to be no problem with other video sites requiring flash. Also the youtube videos play fine in Firefox.

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds?

Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64
Chrome 64 bit Version 25.0.1364.97

Comment: Are you using Adobe Flash Player or Chrome's own built-in plugin (Pepper Flash)? Check which one is in use by typing `about:plugins` in Chrome's address bar and clicking "Details" from right upper corner. Try with both.

Comment: actually both versions seems have been enabled. Things worked once I disabled Pepper Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pilefrocks, the problem is with Pepper Flash. Disable this plugin from the about:plugins (type in Chrome's address bar and click "details" in upper right corner) and enable the Adobe's Flash Plugin. Hope this helps someone with the same issue.